# jQuery: how to detect if a page is called by an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a dynamic website in html/css/javascript without server side scripting)

Some content is dynamically loaded with ajax requests, from remote html files.

I want these html files to be accessed only via ajax requests, and to do a redirection if it's not an ajax call. The reason for this is that if you access them directly, then the css and the rest of the site (menu, etc.) aren't loaded.

So my question is, is there a way to detect the type of request only with Javascript?
Or maybe there's a different approach to solve this problem...?

I am using jQuery to do the ajax calls and I know jquery adds a "X-Requested-With" header to the request. This is pretty easy to handle with php or java for example, but I couldn't find how to do it with jQuery/Javascript...

Comment: You mean a _dynamic_ website that has no server-side scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all your content in a folder named «content»

Then create a .htaccess and place it into the "content" folder, or in the configuration of your apache (better):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 ^content
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-requested-with} !^XMLHttpRequest$
RewriteRule (.*) http://whereyouwanttoredirect.foo [R=301,L]
```

And it should do more or less the job. I'm not a specialist and so maybe the .htaccess should be a bit tune (some apache killers here want to do it?)

Comment: that will do! at least no need for real server-side scripting...
Thanks all for your time and help!

Comment: Nice Answer, better than checking for non-get requests like mine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the one way is to use a cookie.  Still cookies are not really intended for this purpose and you will run into some issues.  If you have some control over the server you could make some pages `post` only.  These would do the ajax stuff.  When pages are "gotten" with `get` they know they are for the browser.

Remember ***there is no secure way to do this*** without server side control.  I'm guessing you don't care.

Answer (score 1):

Some frameworks set `X-Requested-With`, but there is no real way to know what is making the call and it is possible for anyone to fake those headers in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Just think about it, you can't add any dynamic content (redirects) to static websites; also, if you manage to do this on JS, what would happen if it's disabled and so on?

You should not worry about user entering wrong page, because this just won't happen (users should not try to make their own URL)

If you want to do this anyway, make a PHP or some other parser to check if page is not directly accessed, and if not, provide HTML file content to user.

Comment: yes you're right. It's just that, in previous projects, I saw google returning URLs of these type of pages in search results. So users don't do their urls, but they are being redirected too them... On one hand I want google to reference this content, but I don't want the direct link to appear in search results...